# Secure ESPAsyncWebServer with esp32

Tags: esp32

I am successfully using the ESPAsyncWebServer library with an ESP32 
(https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer). 
I would like to use the secure route. The lib offers (ESPAsyncWebServer.h):

```
#if ASYNC_TCP_SSL_ENABLED
    void onSslFileRequest(AcSSlFileHandler cb, void* arg);
    void beginSecure(const char *cert, const char *private_key_file, const char *password);
endif
```

I could not find any information about cert, private_key_file and password.
Does anybody has experience with such a secure route, e.g. where is cert, private_key_file and password defined? Why do I need a password?
Where do I define ASYNC_TCP_SSL_ENABLED?

Thanks.